# Is there a way to bridge two networks and limit their in between connection speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

There is a small office network **A** and another one called **B**. I want to bridge them and be able to limit the connection speed between A and B, and be able to set a custom speed (not predefined).

1. I want clients from **B** to access resources from **A** with a limited speed of 2Mbit (combined).
2. I don't want to limit the speed between clients in **B**.

Is this possible? I haven't purchased a router for **B** so the device needed can also be a router.

The two locations should be connected wirelessly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is most easily done with a "smart switch", which can be located either at the A or B end, and which limits traffic on the A-B link port. In most cases it can limit traffic at different speeds in each direction.

OTOH, some wireless link products include speed limiting - as an example, not to be confused with a product recommendation, EnGenius ENH202 and ENH500 both include this function ("wireless traffic shaping" is the term they use for it - other manufacturers often have something similar, but check before purchase.)